# PIMA alarm system discharging but not recharging backup battery

Tags: pcb, alarm

We moved to a new place with an existing PIMA alarm system.
After changing the backup battery (which we thought was dead) we realized that the new battery worked only once during initial discharge.

The system then started complaining again about the battery.

Besides the backup battery discharging but not recharging, the system seems to work well.
I am assuming all connections are in place as the battery was supplying power on first discharge when the system was disconnected from the mains.

I am also now suspecting the previous battery was not faulty.

Equipped with a multimeter, I have verified that the fuses (F3 and F4 below) are conductive.

An alarm technician offered me to replace the whole system for about 500$ but I feel it may be a minor issue that could be fixed at a much lower cost instead.

I am looking for help figuring out the cause of the issue and how to repair.

Many thanks in advance!

**Documents**

[Link to Installation Manual](https://manualzz.com/doc/6956481/captain-i-installation-manual--eng--rev-j--05-2005)

A partial schematic of the PCB:
[image]

Connection to the mains and 230V - 14V AC adaptor
[image]

Backup Battery

[image]

Whole view of PCB
[image]

Left Side of PCB
[image]

Right Side view of PCB
[image]

Comment: I can't find a question, just a hint of a very broad qeustion. I recommend you go for that $500 part, or you'll likely find out in the end the bill is $500 + a lot of time and perhaps material / tools spent. Besides, don't be cheap on an alarm system.

Comment: I'm not being cheap, I'm protecting the environment! 

Comment: That's very noble of you.

Comment: since you have mains right there in the box, just get an SLA battery charger for it, and wire in parallel instead of trying to fix the PCB's charger. nothing about that should wig out the PCB's controller; it's just voltage on the line like the battery itself would supply when charged. It might (but likely not) warn about a battery problem, but should work regardless.

Comment: @dandavis genius idea! so I can buy a 12V SLA charger of any amperage as long as it's more than 1.35A?

Comment: 1.35A is the 'initial current'. or maybe any current will do it just that it will charge faster or slower?

Comment: slower is better, make sure it's a fancy battery maintainer, or just lightly trickle charge it 24x7 at a few dozen ma, it shouldn't be used often anyway, so speed isn't as important as lifetime.

Comment: by fancy battery maintainer you mean something that will stop charging when the battery is full, right? I am not planning to start plugging it and unplugging it frequently to be honest, I want to put it in the cabinet and forget about it

Comment: wait, i misunderstood, if it has to run from battery, then yes, you need to feed it a little more current than it actually uses. as little extra as possible actually, so you don't fry the battery. 1/50th of the AH, which is 100ma. measure the current it draws from a fully battery to get a precise figure. an old laptop charger at 19v and a DC-DC buck converter with adjustable V+I (13.5v, Ialarm+0.1A) can then run the whole system and keep the battery full. If you get short current pulses above the normal current, the battery will fill in and recharge when it returns to normal.

Comment: no it doesn't have to run from battery, the way it works is as follows: when electricity is flowing in the alarm system from the mains, then it recharges the battery, when the mains stop providing electricity, it starts running on the battery. So I think that your initial suggestion is fine, because when the battery will be charging (connected to the mains), the alarm system will not draw from it. When the system will need the battery (mains down), then it also means the battery is no longer charging

Comment: fair nuff, a charger that claims it safe to leave connected all the time should solve it then.

Comment: thanks, will try that, maximum I will fry an alarm that needs replacement otherwise